# Why do Android captured PNG's throw errors on attempt to render into Prawn PDF

Tags: android, amazon-s3, imagemagick, zlib, prawn

I have an ios/android app that requires a user to sign something on screen then the app captures a screenshot of this signature.  In most situations, this process works fine.  In a few situations, usually related to Samsung Android phones, on the server when I attempt to render the S3 stored screenshot from the phone, PRAWN PDF throws the below error.

```
Zlib::Inflate.inflate(@img_data)
Zlib::DataError: incorrect data check
```

I wasn't able to get any more error information from this so I decided to dig in and look more closely at the underlying data of the file.  My first attempt was to open the file with ImageMagick.

ImageMagick will create an image file object as referenced below,

```
#<MiniMagick::Image:0x007f83b47c9bf8 @path="/var/folders/g2/57tbfl691hg1gyqjkgy4vd6m0000gn/T/mini_magick20150713-2121-6y1as5.png", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/g2/57tbfl691hg1gyqjkgy4vd6m0000gn/T/mini_magick20150713-2121-6y1as5.png (closed)>, @info=#<MiniMagick::Image::Info:0x007f83b47c9bd0 @path="/var/folders/g2/57tbfl691hg1gyqjkgy4vd6m0000gn/T/mini_magick20150713-2121-6y1as5.png", @info={"raw:%m %w %h %b"=>"PNG 2560 970 59926B", "format"=>"PNG", "width"=>2560, "height"=>970, "dimensions"=>[2560, 970], "size"=>59926}>>
```

When I attempted the most basic image file operation I could think of, ie, convert from png to jpg, I received the below error, which references the IDAT data check as being incorrect, this behavior is consistent with the error from PRAWN ie, 'incorrect data check'.

```
MiniMagick::Error: `convert /var/folders/g2/57tbfl691hg1gyqjkgy4vd6m0000gn/T/mini_magick20150713-29731-1urceop.png[0] /var/folders/g2/57tbfl691hg1gyqjkgy4vd6m0000gn/T/mini_magick20150713-29731-10i6sg1.jpg` failed with error:
convert: IDAT: incorrect data check `/var/folders/g2/57tbfl691hg1gyqjkgy4vd6m0000gn/T/mini_magick20150713-29731-1urceop.png' @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1831.
```

I'm unclear how to verify the expected value of IDAT or even how to interpret any patterns that might indicate the data is corrupt.  Below is the meta data for an image that is causing the PRAWN crash.

```
{"x-amz-id-2"=>"BXkVr2k45L6zHSV31aq6tH3oCBp5C9Ncv0fD1zLOh5oW5D0PQHt1i+za3eAat/TezLZQfOyr43E=", "x-amz-request-id"=>"69601E81D15125AD", "date"=>"Mon, 13 Jul 2015 20:29:00 GMT", "last-modified"=>"Mon, 13 Jul 2015 19:14:49 GMT", "etag"=>"\"fe1da1ea421864ddadde17147bbb82a9\"", "accept-ranges"=>"bytes", "content-type"=>"image/png", "content-length"=>"59926", "server"=>"AmazonS3"}
```

The code being used on Android to capture the screenshot is below.

```
original_image = cropImageView.getCroppedImage()
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
original_image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
stream.close();
```

In general, the files being captured are always being successfully captured, stored and retrieved but any attempt to process these particular files causes the PRAWN error.  I'm unclear what direction to take this debugging and would really like some input on how to proceed.

An example image that was captured with a Samsung Android Galaxy Note 4 running android 5.0.1  is stored here, https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bcamarda/original_broken.png for reference and or tinkering if so desired.

Comment: FWIW, using ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 on Ubuntu, I get different messages for **`convert original_broken.png original_broken.jpg`**, in line with [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139824/png-imagemagick-error-extra-compressed-data).

Comment: Ever figure it out? I am getting the same error using ruby and chunky_png to load Android screenshots!